# Blender weight paint looks wrong

Tags: vertex-weights

I'll just point out that i am quite new to using blender.

I have a vertex group where each vertex has a weight of 1.0, however if i look at the weight paint for that group it seems like some vertices have a different weight than 1.0

[image: Weight Paint]

(There shouldn't be any yellow/cyan colors only full red (weight 1.0) and full blue(0.0) as far as i know so this is really confusing to me)

I even tried to write a quick python script to print out weights and it indeed showed that a few weights aren't 1.0, then i wrote a script to set all of them to 1 but that issue didn't go away(even tho this time it does print that every single weight is 1.0 in the selected group)

Any advice would be appreciated, if i had to guess then this happens because of some interpolation but what exactly i have no clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the yellow and green parts. It's just hue interpolation from red to blue (1→0) weighted vertices.

Comment: Thank you, i thought so as well because when i moved the bones, the mesh moved as it should but i still wasn't 100% sure so thanks for clarifying!